# httpclient not working anywhere except in windows phone

Tags: wcf, httpclient, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I followed the [ToDoRest][1] example in github, it works there but it don't working my app I don't understand what I am missing.
Things look same in both projects but still it's not working in mine please help me I am looking into this from last 3 days without any luck. Please help me.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, and explain what "don't working" means.  Does it crash?  Fail silently?  Are there exceptions or error messages?  What have you done to debug?  Which specific platform is causing the problem?  What you have posted so far is not enough information for us to help you, and will just be closed if you do not fix it.

Comment: it tried you put images but due to lack reputation I am unable to post links.
Windows is working but android and IOS not working just fails silently.
Complete images can be found here 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63096/http-client-not-working-anywhere-except-windows-phone?new=1

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://arteksoftware.com/end-to-end-mvvm-with-xamarin/

Comment: Even that uses httpclient which is not working my project. If that works I am done.

Comment: Could some one help me with this please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I need to put .ConfigureAwait(false) at the end each call then it works in IOS and android